Checking if cell from sheet1 exist on sheet2, if exist will insert text from sheet1 to sheet2
My goal is to check if sheet 2 A3 to A120 (End of the row) matches with sheet1 columns I to AP (End of the columns) If it matches, the data from sheet2 B3 will be inserted to the respective columns in sheet1. Any help would be appreciated as I do not know how to start.
Unsure how to insert photo so that I can show a better example. But below is the table i can come up with.
Example:
Sheet1



Column A
Column B




Warnings
0


Temp
39


Cycle
300


Fail
0



Sheet2



Warning
Temp
Cycle
Fail
Data



Expected Results:
Sheet2



Warning
Temp
Cycle
Fail
Data




0
39
300
0





"I to AP" does not make too much sense... Looking to the picture, understanding that you mean "I1:AP1" and returning the value in the second row will it be a correct understanding? Then, supposing that the respective headers will be unique, will it be a correct assumption?

Maybe you need HLOOKUP function?

Please, test the next code. It place the range to be processed in an array then it uses Find function to match the value and load a second array. Its content will be dropped at the end of the code, at once:
Sub MatchAndCopy()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSrc, rngFind As Range, rngSrc As Range, i As Long
 
 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 
 lastR = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column A:A
 arr = ws1.Range("A3:B" & lastR).Value 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 Set rngSrc = ws2.Range("I1:AP1")
 arrSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1).Value
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Set rngFind = rngSrc.Find(what:=arr(i, 1), After:=rngSrc.cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then _
        arrSrc(1, rngFind.column - rngSrc.column + 1) = arr(i, 2)
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content, at once:
 rngSrc.cells(1).Offset(1).Resize(1, UBound(arrSrc, 2)).Value = arrSrc
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
